# Is there any sniffer aplication for Android 2.2?

Tags: applications, 2.2-froyo, networking

Is there any network sniffer program for Android 2.2 similar to Wireshark for Windows?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is [Shark](https://market.android.com/details?id=lv.n3o.shark) that does just this, it requires root, there is also [Pixie](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.nbl.pixie), but it too requires root.

Answer (score 1):

There is also [Packet Sniffer By AndroidArts](http://sites.google.com/site/androidarts/packet-sniffer)

and For Facebook and Youtube...Try [FaceNiff](http://faceniff.ponury.net/)...

Also there is DroidSheep (just like Firesheep) , "Network Spoofer" which uses Debian Image and "Arpspoof" is also good app.

PS: Use Shark For Root Instead of Shark Native

Answer (score 0):

If you had root access to your phone, there are many package sniffers on the market.

Some free are:
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=it.sssup.rtn.sniffer154
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=lv.n3o.shark