# How check what requests does my App (wireshark for Android)?

Tags: internet

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there any sniffer aplication for Android 2.2?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/10112/is-there-any-sniffer-aplication-for-android-2-2)

Is there any kind of wireshark app for Andorid? I would like to see what requests does one application on my Nexus One do, but I have no idea how to check it. Is it possible?

Comment: That other question should have exactly what you need :)